# How can I find out where the firefox bin is?

Tags: filesystems, osx, path, firefox

I am trying to add Firefox to my PATH like in [this](http://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/cs348/unix_path.html) tutorial. I have Firefox in the Applications folder of my GUI on my mac book air. I am familiar with adding locations to my path. But I don't know how to find the firefox executable on my machine. Where does the applications folder go to look for the Firefox executable?

Comment: Refer this thread of stackoverflow :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32175170/firefox-is-showing-cannot-find-firefox-binary-in-path-error-in-mac-os

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The binary would be inside the application bundle.  For example,

> ```
> $ file /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin 
> /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
> /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin (for architecture x86_64):Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
> /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin (for architecture i386): Mach-O executable i386
> ```

You *could* launch Firefox by running `/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox`, and you *could* put `/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS` in your `$PATH` to help you save some typing.  However, the Mac OS X way to launch an application from the command line would be

```
open -a Firefox
```

[open(1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html) is a command-line tool to interact with [Launch Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCIntro/LSCIntro.html).

Answer (score 3):

#### Using type

You can use the command `type` to locate where an executable is coming from on the filesystem.

#### Example

```
$ type -a firefox
firefox is /usr/bin/firefox
```

#### Using locate

If `firefox` is not already on the PATH then interrogating the locate database using the `locate` command might be your only other option. However recently installed items may not show up there until the `updatedb` command has had a chance to index these newly added files to the filesystem.

#### Example

```
$ locate firefox | grep 'firefox$'
/home/saml/.cache/mozilla/firefox
/home/saml/.mozilla/firefox
/home/saml/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/doc/selenium-webdriver-2.5.0/rdoc/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox
/home/saml/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox
/home/saml/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.5.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox
/home/saml/Downloads/MISC/youtubexbmc/youtubexbmc-7c51c2b201a7/extensions/youtube-firefox
/home/saml/SparkleShare/personal_repo/APPS/installed/firefox
/usr/bin/firefox
/usr/lib64/firefox
/usr/lib64/firefox/firefox
```

#### mdfind

If you don't have access to the `locate` facility on OSX you can try using `mdfind` as well to locate occurrences of `firefox`.

Comment: I am getting me$ type -a Firefox
-bash: type: Firefox: not found

Comment: @akh2103 - Try lowercase `firefox`.

Comment: This assumes that `firefox` can already be found from `PATH`, which is what the OP is trying to accomplish.

Comment: Not really applicable to [tag:osx].

Comment: @200_success In what way? `type` is a Bash builtin; OS X, as far as I know, uses Bash as the default shell.

Comment: @200_success - if you search on the other SE sites you'll find a lot of references to exactly this method, so it's apt. I think Joseph's comment is spot on though that this will only work if `firefox` is on the `PATH`. It wasn't clear to me whether it was or wasn't based on the Q. The only other method I can think of beyond interrogating the launcher icon is to use the `locate` command, which Joseph has already highlighted.

Comment: @JosephR. Technically true, but not useful. For one, `type` assumes that `firefox` is already in the `$PATH`, which it wouldn't be on OS X. The question is, _where_ would you find it, which leads back to the original question. See my [tag:osx]-relevant [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/99489).

Comment: @200_success - I've added locate as an alternative given your feedback.

Comment: While `locate` exists on OS X, the locatedb database is [not built by default](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/14836).  Instead, users would probably prefer `mdfind`, since Spotlight indexing is enabled out-of-the-box.

Comment: @200_success - added details on `mdfind`, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this :

```
$ readlink -f $(type -p firefox)
```

if `firefox` is not in the PATH :

```
$ find / -name firefox 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Boy, will that take time!

Comment: Depends of your hardware (for some people, just =~ 3 seconds), but it works. `updatedb` takes time too =)

Comment: True, but not nearly as much as crawling your whole filesystem. `updatedb` is usually run regularly by `cron` to keep the database up-to-date so a new update shouldn't take that long. As for the `find` approach, imagine the worst case scenario where the `firefox` executable is stored under `/ze_tools`!

Comment: @GillesQuenot I joined this community just to upvote your response. Firefox was not in my path and I couldn't find the proper directory I needed for my selenium python script. I thank you for the second line of code you posted- it really helped!

Answer (score 1):

Not quite the same problem, but since I found this answer when googling, I'm providing my solution here too.

I'm trying to find the firefox executable to execute it from scripts like cucumber / selenium tests. Here's what I do:

Find it with  Spotlight

```
firefox_paths = %x[mdfind "kMDItemFSName = Firefox.app"]
firefox_path = firefox_paths.split('\n').first.chomp
firefox_executable_path = File.join(firefox_path, '/Contents/MacOS/firefox')

Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path=firefox_executable_path
```

Another way would be to dump launch services database and grep it out there

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -dump \
  | grep -n7 org.mozilla.firefox \
  | grep path: \
  | awk '{ print($3) }'
```